# load specific menu items for specific users in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i have a default.ctp page in which all the menu items are showing i want to load the specific menu items for the specific user.. and if someone trying to access other menu through url he or she redirected to the dashboard controller ..what is the best way to do this ..

right now in my view page i am doing like this

```
    <?php if($userinfo==1){?>
<li><a href="explorer.html" class="shortcut-medias" title="Media">Media</a></li><?php }?>
```

this code is just hiding the menu but not controlling the urls and also i dont want to write or check in every controller. i want like this whether it should be in controller or in my default.ctp page

```
 if (userinfo == 1 )
  show these menu items
  else 
    redirect to dashboard
```

Comment: You can [ACL and ACO Cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html) for controlling access to your application

Comment: whats your exact requirement ? based on user types/roles menu will display ? or based on users menu will display ?